# Does Grails + Maven + JCL work in conjunction?

Tags: grails

I'm working with IntelliJ IDEA 10.0.1 and Grails 1.3.7. I have a mavenized Grails project which depends on many logging libraries.

Here's the problem:
I have to use JCL as logging framework, but grails per default is working with SLF4J and has some default dependencies like **jcl-over-slf4j**, which are inherited by every grails project. First of all I have excluded every **jcl-over-slf4j** transitive dependency in my project pom file and verified with **mvn dependency:tree** that my pom is clean of any SLF4J bridging libraries.

But nevertheless **jcl-over-slf4j** is still beeing downloaded to my local maven repo when I try to start my grails app. This leads obviously to a StackOverflowError at runtime, since both **jcl-over-slf4j** and **slf4j-jcl** are in the classpath.

So because of which declaration the **jcl-over-slf4j** dependency is still beeing downloaded?

Since my pom is clean the obvious conclusion would be that Grails itself depends on those libraries. As mentioned before Grails has some default dependencies, on which every Grails project depends.

I know that I can exclude inherited depencencies in the BuildConfig.groovy file and if I run **grails dependency-report** I can also see that these dependencies are not listed anymore.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = { 
    inherits("global") {
      excludes "jcl-over-slf4j", "jul-to-slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"
    }
}
```

But even then the **jcl-over-slf4j** dependency is still beeing downloaded to my repo when I start my grails app! Am I missing something? Is there a different way to exclude inherited grails dependencies when you're using a mavenized grails project?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks! 
Slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got the answer now..

The problem is that the defined **maven-grails-plugin** (which is mandatory when you use maven + grails) within my pom file depends on jcl-over-slf4j and therefore gets downloaded when I start my application through maven. With my current maven version (2.2.1) it's not possible to exclude a dependency from a plugin. There is also a jjira issue regarding this problem. [Can not exclude a dependency from a plugin](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2448)

As soon as I remove the **maven-grails-plugin** the dependency is not downloaded anymore, but as drawback I'm not able to start the application through maven anymore..

Lessons learned: Don't use Maven + Grails + JCL in conjunction.

Note that with **mvn dependency:tree** just project dependencies are listed, but plugin dependencies are **NOT** listed.

Hope this is of any help!
Regards Slash

Comment: **mvn dependency:resolve-plugins** could possibly help to list plugin dependencies

Comment: Thx for the hint! When I let it run, it reveals that the **grails-maven-plugin** has no dependency(at least no direct dependency) to **jcl-over-slf4j**. But why is it then still beeing downloaded?